# How to reopen a dialog programatically

Tags: java, dialog, swt, jface

I have a JFace dialog and a toggle button( whose text is either "freeze" or "unfreeze") in the button bar.

Initially i select an object and click on a menu item to open the dialog.

From then on, whenever I click on toggle button(when text on it is "unfreeze") the dialog should close and reopen.

How do i achieve this ?

Comment: So when it gets reopened, should it still contain whatever the user entered before?

Comment: Does it need to close and reopen, could you not use a modeless dialog and just update the contents?

Comment: @Baz Basically inside the button listener, the object selected to open the dialog will be revised and the revised object should be the new input to the dialog. So i thought the dialog should be programatically re-opened with the new input.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes it needs to be reopened with a new target input to the dialog.

Comment: @user1168608 Have a look at my answer. In the listener, you can call a method of the dialog that sets your new content before you make it visible again.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea how to do it (quick hack):

```
private static MyDialog dialog;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Button openDialog = new Button(shell, SWT.TOGGLE);
    openDialog.setText("Toggle dialog");

    openDialog.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            if (openDialog.getSelection())
            {
                if (dialog == null)
                {
                    dialog = new MyDialog(new Shell(display));
                    dialog.open();
                }

                if(dialog.getShell() != null && !dialog.getShell().isDisposed())
                    dialog.getShell().setVisible(openDialog.getSelection());
            }
            else
            {
                if (dialog != null && dialog.getShell() != null && !dialog.getShell().isDisposed())
                    dialog.getShell().setVisible(openDialog.getSelection());
            }
        }
    });

    shell.open();
    shell.pack();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }

    display.dispose();
}

private static class MyDialog extends Dialog
{

    public MyDialog(Shell parentShell)
    {
        super(parentShell);
        setShellStyle(SWT.CLOSE | SWT.MODELESS | SWT.BORDER | SWT.TITLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent)
    {
        Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
        Text text = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER);

        return container;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureShell(Shell newShell)
    {
        super.configureShell(newShell);
        newShell.setText("Some dialog");
    }

    @Override
    protected Point getInitialSize()
    {
        return new Point(450, 300);
    }
}
```

---

It will create and open the dialog on first press of the button and hide/unhide in on consequent press events (using `Shell#setVisible(boolean)`).

If this is not what you had in mind, please update your question or post a comment.

Comment: The toggle button should lie inside the "MyDialog" class

Comment: @user1168608 Well, then how do you want to press it once the dialog is hidden?

Comment: I'm trying to re-call the dialog from the handler registered against the menu handler. Basically my requirement is , by a click on the button (which lies within the dialog), the dialog closes and reopens itself with new input.

Comment: @user1168608 Why do you have to close it? Why not simply update the content?